# Android passing list from fragment to viewPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio

Fragment:-

```
public class HomeProductFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_product, container, false);


        userService = ApiUtils.getUserService();
        Call<ProductCategoryDetails> callCategory = userService.getProductCategoryJSON();
        callCategory.enqueue(new Callback<ProductCategoryDetails>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProductCategoryDetails> call, Response<ProductCategoryDetails> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.body() != null && response.body().getData() != null) {
                        for(int j = 0;j<response.body().getData().getCategories().size();j++) {
                            productCategory = response.body().getData().getCategories().get(j).getMainCategory();
                            data.add(productCategory);
                        }
                        Log.d("SET321","==set=="+data);
                        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
                        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
                        viewPagerAdapter.setData(data); <-----------

                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error!======" + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d("TEST123","Exception");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProductCategoryDetails> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("TAG","FailedCat");
            }
        });
```

ViewPagerAdapter:-

```
private List<String> data;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    public void setData(List<String> data){
        this.data = data;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TabFragment.getInstance(position);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String[] stockArr = new String[data.size()];
        return stockArr[position];
        //return data.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        String[] stockArr = new String[data.size()];
        return stockArr.length;
        //return data.size();
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        String[] stockArr = new String[data.size()];
        return stockArr.length;
        //return data.size();
    }
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
>           at com.custom_adapters.ViewPagerAdapter.getCount(ViewPagerAdapter.java:43)

Comment: Adapter trying to call `size()` on a null `List`. Your list `data` is not initialised and therefore its `null`

Answer (score 0):

Your data list can be passed as constructor arguement, that is remove the setData method in adapter and make the constructor as

```
  ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager,List<String> data){
         super(manager);
         this.data = data;
    }
```

Comment: really helped.. one more ,data is list. i want data as string[] type, i tried converting  String[] stockArr = new String[data.size()];  but getting like this (in log)- string[] == [Ljava.lang.String;@68bd822

Answer (score 0):

To simply fix it, do `viewPagerAdapter.setData(data);` **before** `viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);`

Comment: really helped.. one more ,data is list. i want data as string[] type, i tried converting String[] stockArr = new String[data.size()]; but getting like this (in log)- string[] == [Ljava.lang.String;@68bd822 –

Comment: You're `println`ing the string array to log?

Comment: String[] stockArr = new String[data.size()];
Log.d("AD123","==string[]=="+stockArr);

Comment: That's what supposed to happen. If you want to log the content of an array you have to do it yourself, in a loop.

Comment: String url = sharedPreferences.getString("url", "urldefault");  vidView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(url); <--- url for video
        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        vidView.start();   is it possible to get the size of the video?

Comment: That's another question and we cannot guess without context.